# Как очистить содержимое div на стороне сервера?

Tags: php, ajax

```
<div class='item'>
  <p>Askoll M239 (M231)</p>
</div>
```

Как по клику очистить содержимое .item в файле 1.html, то есть удалить из файла `<p>Askoll M239 (M231)</p>`?

Comment: по клику на что?

Comment: на кнопку  <button>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В самом общем виде - как-то так. Но это чистый js - php и ajax тут не используются. Возможно, Вы что-то другое имели в виду?

```js
let item = document.querySelector('.item');
let child = document.querySelector('p');
let button = document.querySelector('button');

button.onclick = function() {
  item.removeChild(child);
}
```

```html
<div class='item'>
  <p>Askoll M239 (M231)</p>
</div>
<br />
<button>очистить по клику</button>
```

Comment: Должно удалять на стороне сервера, а не клиента. Это трудно реализовать?

Comment: @НаталіяЦвігун, ну да, это, пожалуй, посложнее будет: нужно по клику на клиенте отправлять на сервер задание, чтобы php-скрипт читал файл 1.html, находил там конкретный div с конкретным содержимым и удалял его - логика примерно такая